# update row from datagridview to database

Tags: vb.net

I have a script to update the value from datagridview to database. 
I do use a button insert ToolStripButton but it is not working.

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn = New SqlConnection("")
    conn.Open()
    Dim query As [String] = "SELECT * FROM dtaTraLoiChoVanBan"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
    Dim cb As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    C1FlexGrid1.DataSource = dt
    conn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStrip1_ItemClicked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles ToolStrip1.ItemClicked
    Select Case e.ClickedItem.Name
        Case "ToolStripButton1" '---> button insert
            da.Update(dt)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to confirm: You are not really using a blank connection string: "" (did you only remove that for SO)?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code will reload the grid every time and wipe any changes your user is adding.  Try running the grid binding only the first time, by checking for Page.IsPostBack().  You also never used the CommandBuilder to generate an INSERT statement.

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    conn = New SqlConnection("")  'blank connection string won't really work
    conn.Open()
    Dim query As [String] = "SELECT * FROM dtaTraLoiChoVanBan"
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
    Dim cb As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    cb.GetInsertCommand()
    dt = New DataTable()
    da.Fill(dt)
    conn.Close()
    If Not Page.IsPostBack() Then
        C1FlexGrid1.DataSource = dt
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I just added validate to solve it.

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton5.Click
    Me.Validate()
    DataGridView1.EndEdit()
    da.Update(dt)
    MsgBox("Data Updated!!")
    Me.BindGrid()
End Sub
```